# Timescaledb - Creating hypertable through Java/JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, timescaledb

We can successfully create `hypertable` for a standart table on `PgAdmin` but we fail the same query when we run it on `Java`.

The code is:

```
sql = "SELECT create_hypertable('test.conditions', 'time', create_default_indexes => false, migrate_data => true)";
```

The error is:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function create_hypertable(unknown, unknown, create_default_indexes => boolean, migrate_data => boolean) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 8
```

This line works perfect on PgAdmin:

```
SELECT create_hypertable('test.conditions', 'time', create_default_indexes => false, migrate_data => true)
```

How can we fix this?

Comment: Could you try the following to troubleshoot your issue?

```
sql = "SELECT create_hypertable('test.conditions'::regclass, 'time'::name, create_default_indexes => false, migrate_data => true)";
```

This explicitly sets the parameters to the expected types.

If this does not work, try the following to make sure the function is installed in that database and schema:

```sql
SELECT
    nspname,
    proname
FROM
    pg_proc
JOIN
    pg_namespace pn ON (pronamespace=pn.oid)
WHERE
    proname = 'create_hypertable';
```

Comment: When I run the above SQL, I see one result: `nspname: public proname: create_hypertable.` But I'm trying to create hypertable in another schema. How can I do this? The problem seems to be I do not have authority to create hypertable in this other schema.

Comment: I guess this question is worth a bit of troubleshooting, which may be better served on our public slack channel at https://slack.timescale.com/

Comment: Since the method was in public, adding public before the call fixed the problem. This works: `sql = "SELECT public.create_hypertable('test.conditions', 'time', create_default_indexes => false, migrate_data => true)";`